# Component won't load after ejecting angular-cli webpack config

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I followed instructions in [ng2-fullpage](https://github.com/meiblorn/ng2-fullpage) to integrate it in my angular app generated with [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). The only instruction I didn't follow was to update the webpack vendors entry file (src/vendor.browser.ts) with 'jquery' and 'fullpage.js' imports. The fullpage.js port works. So far so good.

Afterwards, I wanted to use a custom webpack config in my angular-cli app. So, I executed the `ng eject` command to get the internal webpack config file. Right after using that command, the app won't bootstrap `AppComponent` with no error message. The app seems to work when I remove the `MnFullPageDirective` from my `NgModule` declarations. Once I insert it back, the `AppComponent` won't load.

It probably has to do with the webpack vendor entry file update, but I don't know how to make it work with `angular-cli` since I'm not familiar with webpack.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**UPDATE**

Here is a github repo which reproduces the situation: https://github.com/koslambrou/angular-cli-ng2-fullpage-ejected

Comment: Do you have github repo that reproduces it?

Comment: @yurzui I added the github repo link

Comment: Thanks for the github repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated your problem and discovered that you need to change your webpack configuration a bit:

Replace

```
module.exports = {
  "devtool": "source-map",
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
```

with

```
module.exports = {
  "devtool": "source-map",
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
      path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules")
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules")
    ]
  },
```

[image]